# .htaccess - redirect all to index.php, but redirect particular link to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

*I read similar questions on stackoverflow, but haven't found solution to my problem.*

In my **.htaccess**, I have:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I need to add one more redirect. I have a real site page - **domain.com/some_real_page**, and I need a shorter link for it - **domain.com/link**. How is this possible?

Tried to do the following, but it is not working:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some_real_page$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/link [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Change the order of your patterns, so the specific one is first, and the general one is last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.  First, the more specific rewrite rule has to come before the general one.  Second, your specific rewrite rule is backwards.

`RewriteEngine` processes rules from top to bottom, much like a programming `if/else if/else`.  This means that you want to put your catch-all case (aka the `^(.*)$`) at the bottom of the list.  All rules before this need the `[L]` attribute to stop further processing after they are matched.

For the second part, you want to make the *browser* link `http://www.domain.com/link` point to the actual file `http://www.domain.com/some_real_page.php`.  In your sample code, you are doing the opposite.

The end result should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/link$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some_real_page.php [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Offtopic. Can you advice some good book about apache and its configuration?

Comment: I've always just used the Apache Documentation (here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/).  It's very thorough.  Otherwise just use Google  :)

Comment: There appeared a problem. Ajax stop working when I add a new RewriteRule and RewriteCond...

Comment: I remove R=302 and it AJAX is working, but redirect stops working.

Comment: Check the URLs used in your AJAX scripts and make sure they're not being redirected incorrectly

Comment: URLs like "/folder/controller.php", i.e. absolute. "make sure they're not being redirected incorrectly". How can I do it?

Comment: Try moving the first two RewriteConds to above the last RewriteRule.  That should exclude rewriting for end files